# Why can't I adopt this child in Skyrim: Hearthfire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have a child's bed and chest, and I've tried a single bed, but for some reason the game just won't let me adopt the little girl on the streets I want. I've tried different ways and I have no idea how to do everything, and I can't go back to the safe before the bed, because that's way too far back. I'm playing on Xbox One.

I tried to see if there was a console command I can do on here, which I can't. I've tried going back to a last save and redoing it, but as soon as I get that child's bed and chest it says it's owned, even though I have no one in my house. The only person I have is a follower, but she doesn't live with me. Do any of you experience this and do you have a way for the Xbox One users to figure things out?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community! Just a few question to make a few things clear: Which house are you talking about? Do you own any other houses? How many houses did you build? Did you finish building this house? Did you send your houescarl to your house?

Answer (score 3):

In order to adopt a child, either a house with a children's bedroom, or a homestead furnished with a bed AND a chest is required.

In a homestead, a child's bed can be fitted in the Bedrooms or a single bed fitted in the Main Hall. When in the Main Hall, the dresser in between the two single beds counts as a chest for both possible children. Otherwise, if there are two child beds, there must be two child chests. If there are two beds but one chest, adoption will still not be allowed.

If you have met these prerequisites, but you still can't adopt, then it's likely that you haven't yet completed the "Innocence Lost" quest AND spoken to Constance Michel about adoption.  Adopting a child from Honorhall Orphanage is only possible if the quest "Innocence Lost" has been completed and the headmistress, Grelod the Kind, is dead. Once that is done, go outside and wait for 48 in-game hours, then re-enter Honorhall Orphanage and talk to Constance Michel.

If you skip the wait and the return trip to HO, a courier will eventually deliver her "consider adoption" letter, at which point you can talk to Constance and adopt.

from http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Adoption